# distinct not removing duplicate from laravel elequent

Tags: mysql, laravel

i am trying to remove the duplicates from a laravel elequent query result like below :

```
        
$helping_hand = Model::where('user_id','2')->where('amount','>',0)->get();
```

now this model returns 8 result with the same comment_id in the model but for each comment id i want it to be appeared once in the result so when i add

```
$helping_hand = Model::where('user_id','2')->distinct('comment_id')->where('amount','>',0)->get();
```

it wont remove the duplicates from the result . is there any wat to do this with distinct because i dont wanna use group by . thanks in advance

Comment: try this on collection `$q = $helping_hand->unique('comment_id');`

Comment: _Small Point_ Distinct does not have a parameter, like in a raw query DISTICT applies to the query and not just one of the columns